# Error message when opening a file

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6

I just got a java project from a friend of mine but whenever i go to open it in net beans i get an error message saying that
"Problem:  the project uses the java platform called JDK_1.6 but this platform was not found
solution: click resolve and create new platform called JDK_1.6"

can anyone help me open the project?

Comment: Create a platform for the project with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Java JDK 1.6 installed? If not, you have to change the java platform version (in the properties of the java project). Or you install Java JDK 1.6 ;)

Comment: It's not *just* a matter of having JDK 1.6, it's a matter of defining the JDK with a specific name inside NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

### You Could

Download and install [Java JDK 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR)

In Netbeans, goto Tools > Java Platforms.  Click [Add Platform], Select [Java Standard Edition] and click [Next], Browse to the location that you have installed Java 6 JDK to and select [Finish].  You should then be able to name the platform if you wish.

### Or You Could

Right click the project node, select [Properties].  Under the "Source" category, make souce that the Source/Binary Format is JDK 6.  Under the "Libraries" category, select the default JDK from the Java Platform combobox or change it to whatever you want.